# Resizing a VideoView

Tags: android, resize, android-videoview

I need to resize a VideoView, but it has to be bigger than the screen. I found out that it's possible by overriding VideoView's onMeasure, like this:

```
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(twotimesscreenwidth, twotimesscreenheight);
    }
```

In most cases, this works perfectly. I tested it without any problems on a range of devices (Nexus One, HTC Wildfire, HTC Sensation, Samsung Galaxy S2, Galaxy Gio, Galaxy Tab 10.1, Motorola Xoom). But when testing it on a HTC Desire HD or Nexus S, I notice it doesnt resize like it has to. On the Desire HD it resizes to the screen width and a bit more than the screen height, while on the Nexus S it's just fullscreen.

Does anybody know why this is happening, and more importantly, how I can solve this? I already found several questions about this, but all without any solution :(

Comment: can you provide complete source code for this....I will be a great help to me

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting layout parameters to display.getWidth() * 2 or whatever multiplier you wish to specify and similarly set its height with respect to display.getHeight()
Hope it helps

btw let me know if you are playing live video streams. Mine get stuck at times

Comment: The width and height of the view are fine. The VideoView is inside a RelativeLayout which has width and height 2 times the size of the screen, while the video has a match_parent size. When I set a background image, I see the view's dimensions are correct. Only the video doesn't resize.

Also I'm working with a downloaded video file, so no livestream, sorry